# mixture of recursive and loop

Tags: java, loops, recursion

So I have a recursion problem.

Write a program that will predict the size of a population of organisms. The program should ask for the starting number of organisms, their average daily population increase (as a percentage), and the number of days they will multiply.
For example, a population might begin with two organisms, have an average daily increase of 50 percent, and will be allowed to multiply for seven days. The program should use a loop to display the size of the population for each day.
Input Validation:

- Do not accept a number less than 2 for the starting size of the population.
- Do not accept a negative number for average daily population increase.
- Do not accept a number less than 1 for the number of days they will multiply.
- Make sure your program uses a recursive method instead of a loop to calculate the number of organisms.
- Please document pre and post conditions at the beginning of any method you are completing. If none exists then state none for each.

We have to write a `displayPopulation` method which will display the population size of each day. Then, we have to write the recursive method to calculate the size and then we have the main for input validation.

Now, I have the main and the recursive method. What I can't figure out is how to make a loop display the size each day? 
Following is my recursive method:

```
private static double showPopulation(int dayNum, int days, double organisms, double dailyIncrease){

  if(dayNum==days)
      return organisms;
   else 

        return showPopulation(dayNum+1, days, organisms + organisms*(dailyIncrease/100), dailyIncrease);
}
```

I know this will give me the size of all days combined. I don't know how to store each value and make it print in a loop in a different method.I am really lost. I need some help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried anything for displayPopulation? If not, how would you solve it verbally? That sometimes helps me determine a working algorithm.

Comment: `@Rabia Khan` If you found any Ans. Help full than you can Mark that as Accepted .

Answer (score 1):

write a method inside any for or while loop and call this method passing the value expected by method. and print the result.

Note- I am not writing the code as that should be done by you.first you try and write code and then also if you are got getting any output ,then we can check your code and will try to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double showPopulation(int dayNum, int days, double organisms, double dailyIncrease){         
    if(dayNum==days)
        return organisms;
    else{ 
        //put your print statement here  population in `days` is  `organisms`
        return showPopulation(dayNum+1, days, organisms + organisms*(dailyIncrease/100),            dailyIncrease); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double showPopulation(int dayNum, int days, double organisms, double dailyIncrease)
{
     if(dayNum==days)
          return organisms;
       else 
    {
        System.out.println("Population for day"+(dayNum+1)+" is "+(organisms+organisms*(dailyIncrease/100)));
        return showPopulation(dayNum+1, days, organisms + organisms*(dailyIncrease/100), dailyIncrease);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double PrintPopulation(int numDays, int days,
        double organism, double increase) {
    if (numDays == days)
        return organism;
    else {
        double recentPopulation = organism + (organism * increase / 100);
        System.out.println("Population for day:" + numDays + " is: "
                + recentPopulation);
        return PrintPopulation(numDays + 1, days, recentPopulation,
                increase);
    }

}
```

This should solve your issue.
days is the total number of days

Answer (score -1):

Your current program returns organisms on a given day. If you want organisms from 1 to nth day then you can use a for loop as below :

```
double[] organismsArr = new double[days];
for(int i=1;i<=days;i++)
organisms[i-1] = showPopulation(i, days, organisms + organisms*(dailyIncrease/100), dailyIncrease);
```